# enumerate the 0,1 element in each index of list

Tags: for-loop, enumeration, enumerate

I want to get all possible enumeration results, which have 0 or 1 as value in each index.

Below is my code and the result.
How can I improve my code? I want to avoid too many `for` loops.

```
k=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
list_dic={}
for a in range(2):
    k[0]=a
    for b in range(2):
        k[1]=b
        for c in range(2):
            k[2]=c
            for d in range(2):
                k[3]=d
                for e in range(2):
                    k[4]=e
                    for f in range(2):
                        k[5]=f
                        list_dic[tuple(k)]=0

enum_list=list((list_dic.keys()))
print(enum_list)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try with intertools:

```
import itertools
k = [0,1]

ret = itertools.product(k, repeat = 6)

for i in ret:
    print i
```

output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
(...many arrays..)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

with repeat = 6 you set the large of the array out get in combination array store in k, in k you can put any value and intertools try to order and combine then